# Find max value in json even when not existing in some strings Python

Tags: python, max

I have a json like this:

```
{
'tester': [{
    'bbox': [159.50451898338267, 184.94235347135182, 342.8551702886517, 443.9425698127003],
    'score': 0.9999966621398926,
    'post': 43.10764727758942,
    'class': 'Test'
}, {
    'bbox': [564.0261332136855, 14.13539395667492, 580.3409768964439, 38.84439850201004],
    'score': 0.9937067627906799
}, {
    'bbox': [462.02023603048644, 10.929288388749383, 477.8772119836293, 29.733179334594],
    'score': 0.9837657809257507
}],
'status': 'ok'
```

}

The json can contain more strings.

Im trying to get the max value from Post using this code:

```
max_age = max(quality['tester'], key=lambda x: x['post'])
```

The problem im facing is that the key Post does not exists in every string so I get a key error using this code

Comment: `lambda x: x.get('post', float('-inf'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to ignore entries that do not contain the `post` key, this should work:

```py
max_age = max(filter(lambda x: 'post' in x, quality['tester']), key=lambda x: x['post'])
```

You may also want to provide a default value (otherwise `max` will crash if there is the sequence is empty), or even this variant if you are only interested in the maximum `post` value, and not the entry whose `post` value is maximal:

```py
max_age = max(x['post'] for x in quality['tester'] if 'post' in x))
```

Comment: Maybe you meant the `in` operator instead of `hasattr`?

Comment: @BlackBeans, it will be more efficient to return default very low value than filter entire list before.

Comment: Is it? Using generators is pretty efficient. I haven't tested numerically, but in theory there is no reason for it to be slower. Also, it provides a better control over what to do if you there is no value, because you explicitly tell the computer what the default value should be (simply testing if the result is `-infinity` works for as long as you don't allow `-infinity` to be a value in your data stream).

Comment: Also, the efficiency loss (if any) is arguably compensated by the fact that this code is more readable than its `-infinity` counterpart, because understand right away that you are not interested in the entries that do not have a `post` key.

Comment: @BlackBeans, it definitely is, because both *generator expression* and *generator returned by `filter()`* add one more layer which leads to iteration over sequence twice *(worst case)*. And there's no `-inf` in JSON, so you are safe.

Comment: Really? I have tried writing a generator that prints a message each time `__next__` is called, and filtering it does not seem to trigger `__next__` more than not filtering. And, somehow, it's logical: when a `filter` object's `__next__` method is invoked, one would expect it to call it's argument's `__next__` method until its value satisfies the condition, then returning it, which does only one iteration over the sequence.

Comment: @BlackBeans, as I said it adds one more layer in call chain which can't improve productivity. Instead of iterating over sequence which already exists in memory you add chain of calls for every element.

Comment: But you already add a chain of calls for every element... that's the `key` function. Basically, adding a `filter` in front of it just separates the if condition in the code, but what is executed is roughly the same: in your case, the if statement is implicit in the `.get` method. In both cases, you get constant time overhead for each element, so I don't see why the filter version would be inferior. Incidentally, I tried  and the result is that the filter version is about twice faster. Here is the code I tried https://gist.github.com/TheBlackBeans/d11cedbba2880269aff226b4068b8ca2.